# Life cycle of ssh connection

Tags: date, authentication, connection, solaris, sunos

I want to know really what does the "PrintLastLog yes" do in the background,
When I try to connect it's showing me the last login section, I'm searching for the command whose allows me get that result 
I have a SunOS machine and I didn't find command to get the date of last login with the **year**

```
bash-[510]$ last root
root   pts/1        192.168.0.106    Wed Jun 13 18:16   still logged in
```

that's why I'm looking for the source to get that value :

`Last login: *Wed Dec 25 11:53:27 2019* from srvsunos.control-dev.com`

Comment: This is standard behavior (not only for `last` command). If the date is less than one year you do not have it printed. If you check for old records (more than year old) you will see this field.